# Does regular earplug usage come with health risks?

Tags: medical-science, ear

[SteadyHealth](http://ic.steadyhealth.com/earplugs-benefits-and-health-risks) writes:

> Regardless, wearing these earplugs in the long run may prove to have certain health risks as well. The long-term earplugs may lead to excessive accumulation of earwax and debris inside the ear, possibly leading to the occurrence of tinnitus, hearing loss, ear discharge, pain or infections in the area.

Is that an accurate description of problems caused by earplugs?

Comment: The claim that they "may" be harmful is not disprovable. They don't claim there's evidence of of harm, they are merely stating a theory. The question is opinion based, since it requires to define what "may" might mean: is an occurrence of 1 case in a 1,000,000 enough to support this statement? 100? 1 percent? 50%? All these are evidence that they "might" be harmful, but they tell us nothing about the claim.

Comment: @Sklivz-Contrary to your comment, such myths regarding ear plugs causing infection or irittation exists out there which is refuted here-https://ohsonline.com/Articles/2012/10/01/Dispelling-Hearing-Protection-Myths.aspx and http://goaskalice.columbia.edu/answered-questions/ear-plugs. Medically advised methods to avoid or prevent such infections is to periodically clean ear plugs with cleansing agents and dry it before reuse and  stop wearing earplugs beyond their shelf life as mentioned here-http://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/893193O/earlog-17.pdf? fn=EARLog%2017.pdf.